# c++ struct code withi possible enum declaration

Tags: c++, struct

I am a newbie with C++. I am trying to understand a part of code written by a previous colleague but could not figure out the following declaration. Would you please help me to explain this.

```
struct Garuns: Model_hybrid{
DECLARE_MODEL(Garuns)
DECLARE_ODE(0.2,1,
        G,A,R,U,N,S,
        W,
        X,
        W_star,
        X_star,
        GU, DT, ME)
DECLARE_EVENT_OUT(
        nubile,
        parturition,
        invalid
    )

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This piece of code appears to use custom macros that are declared somewhere else in your code, and they are not defined anywhere in the C++ standard. Who knows what they do. You have to figure out what the macros expand to, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like DECLARE_* are function like macros. They are executed before compilation starts. You can read more on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_preprocessor.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I will look for this.